# Servlet - Variable scope best practice for DataSource connection

Tags: java, servlets, scope, datasource

I have developed a servlet to authenticate user based on their client certificate.
However, I've made a mistake by placing some variables in the class definition so they are shared between session.
I should have placed them into the doGet method.

Now I would like to get an advice about DataSource best practice.
I declare the InitialContext and Datasource in the class and init them in the init method.
I declare the Connection inside the doGet where I do the ds.getConnection.
Is my following code correct ?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class readclientcertificate extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=windows-1252";
    // moved in doGet private X509Certificate cert;
    // moved in doGet private String strUUID = "";
    // moved in doGet private String strFormsURL = "";
    private InitialContext ic;
    private DataSource ds = null;       

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException, NamingException {
        super.init(config);
        ic = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource)ic.lookup("jdbc/OracleCoreDS");        
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();               
        X509Certificate cert = null;
        String strUUID = "";
        String strFormsURL = "";        
        Connection conn = null;
        // Retreive Certificate
        try{        
            X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
            cert = certs[0];                    
        } catch(Exception e){
          out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        // Connect to DB and Insert Certificate Informations.
        if (cert != null) {
            try {

               conn = ds.getConnection();           
               Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
               ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select K$LOGON.FA_ADD_CERTIFICATE('" + cert.getSerialNumber() + "','" + cert.getSubjectDN() + "','" + request.getRemoteAddr() + "','" + request.getRemoteHost() + "','"  + request.getRequestURL() + "','" +strFormsURL + "') from dual");
               while (rs.next()) {
                strUUID = rs.getString(1);
               }
               conn.close();

            } catch (SQLException se) {
               throw new ServletException(se);
            } catch (NamingException ne) {
               throw new ServletException(ne);
            }      
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's alright, the datasource is handle by the application server. So there is only one instance of datasource for a jndi key, you can share the datasource instance... NOT the connection instance